# Looking for Tools to Create ASP.NET Web Page Layouts

Tags: asp.net

I'm very new to ASP.NET and creating web pages, my previous experience has all been creating WinForms apps.  I am having a bit of a rough time just getting the layout of pages the way I want.  Whereas I have been used to just dragging and dropping controls exactly where I wanted them on a Windows Form, the VWD development environment for ASP pages seems very fragmented to me with its master pages, content pages, CSS files etc.

What I'd like to know is are there any add-ins or design programs that could greatly simplify designing web pages, so that I can get on with the code behind aspect of my site, rather than spending so long simply trying to get the presentation right?

Comment: Do you want to create data driven webpages (just present lot of data from a database and have users to interact with)? Or do you have less data and want a striking presentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I can understand moving from WInForms to the Web can be confusing at first.

It's all about understanding HTML and in particular the flow of elements combined with CSS.
There are some tools around (Even visual studio in design mode), but they usually create crappy HTML or a lot of fixed layouts that will not do well on tablets, phones etc.

If you are new, focus on MVC and getting a framework (Example Twitter Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) should get you up and running quite quickly.

For more info about positioning: 
http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning

Comment: Positioning: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: that link was very helpful - if you want to post it as the answer I will mark it as my chosen answer accordingly.

Comment: @PJW added the link to my answer

Answer (score 1):

@Pleun made a good comment about using **Twitter Bootstrap** and **ASP.NET-MVC**. I'd like to add to it that there is a good library that ties these two together even further:

[TwitterBootstrapMVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570762/TwitterBootstrapMvc)

You end up writing even less code compare to what you'd have to write. The whole experience indeed becomes similar to drag and drop.